# Python 2.7: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars (in datetime.timedelta)

Tags: python, numpy, overflow, timedelta

I receive the warning **RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars** when I use numbers of type **numpy.int32** for initializing a timedelta. The numbers are not so big that an overflow should be expected.

The following code shows the problem:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = numpy.int32(2147)
    b = numpy.int32(2148)
    print timedelta(seconds = a)      # works well
    print timedelta(seconds = int(b)) # works well
    print timedelta(seconds = b)      # bad result
```

This gives the output:

```
0:35:47
0:35:48
-1 day, 23:24:13.032704
[...]test.py:10: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
print timedelta(seconds = b)
```

I have tested some numbers. It seems to work well for numbers <= 2147 and gives a warning for numbers >= 2148.

I'm looking forward to explanations :)

Comment: When I try to run your code I get `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.int32` so maybe this unexpected behaviour has been simple turned into an error in my release. I'm using numpy 1.11.1 and Python 3.5.2

Comment: I get the same `TypeError` with Python 2.7.12 and numpy 1.11.2. Maybe you could work with `numpy.timedelta64`?